# Web App Tool to figure out memory usage of a link

Tags: software-development, web-development, programming, memory-management, chromebook

I'd like to figure out the memory cost of a link, eg `foobar.com`, as would be used if  a general-purpose laptop/cbk would load it.

Ideally the webpage has an input field where I can type `foobar.com`, and it would show an analysis or a result of ram usage. Eg:

- `foobar.com` eg 20.2 MB
- `stackoverflow.com` eg 192 MB
- `hackernews.com` eg 25.3 MB
- `wikipedia.org` eg 38.5 MB

(Ideally I can enter multiple links and it will perform foreach.)

Comment: Knowing the why can help in answering the question

Comment: @RohitGupta, for integrity/sec. (like virustotal; to know if I should click a link)

Comment: Not sure what kind of "security" it provides. If such tool existed, the author of malicious website could fairly easily just set it up so that the tool gets a different version and shows false information. Probably why none exists.

Comment: @Destroy666, re "*not sure any integrity/sec*" because "*the tool gets a different v*"; It is true that we can both load the same url while I get a significantly different response. [ [Obviously, as that's simply how the web works.](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/reddit) ] But what are the chances? 49 out of 100 times? 4.9? 0.49?